# How does scope work in a .cmd file?

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a .cmd file script that I run to check whether a user is in an AD group or not.

The process is like so:

1. Update their AD GROUP list
2. Check if they have the correct groups to install the apps
3. if the result of the function is `N` then skip to next check

Here is my script:

```
REM ======== SET variables ========
SET @ADGroups=C:\APPS\%USERNAME%\ADGroups.txt


REM ========  update AD groups ========
gpresult /r  > %@ADGroups% 


REM ======== APP1 =========
call:Check_ADGroup "App1 Name"
IF %@InGroupYN% == Y  (
    call:Install_App
) 

REM ======== APP2 =========
call:Check_ADGroup "App2 Name"
IF %@InGroupYN% == Y  (
    call:Install_App
)
```

---

```
::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function Check In AD GROUP
::--------------------------------------------------------
:Check_ADGroup

SET @Result=[]
SET @InGroupYN=N

FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('FINDSTR /rc:"%~1" %@ADGroups%') DO SET @Result=%%a


IF @Result == [] (
    REM ======== Set to No ======== 
    SET @InGroupYN=N

) ELSE (
    REM ======== Set to Yes ======== 
    SET @InGroupYN=Y
)
goto:eof
```

For some reason `@InGroupYN` is always running as `Y` regardless of whether the function is returning true or false

Is there some scoping that needs to be considered with variables in command line?

Comment: Your code should work in my opinion, I cannot find any bad mistake. Do you expect the AD groups to match case-sensitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your structure…

Why not use `If Defined` instead like this:

```bat
Rem ======== SET variables ========
Set "@ADGroups=C:\APPS\%UserName%\ADGroups.txt"

Rem ========  update AD groups ========
GPResult /R > "%@ADGroups%"

Rem ======== APP1 =========
Call :Check_ADGroup "App1 Name"
If Defined @InGroupYN (
    Call :Install_App
)

Rem ======== APP2 =========
Call :Check_ADGroup "App2 Name"
If Defined @InGroupYN (
    Call :Install_App
)
```

---

Then remove the unnecessary `For` loop and `If`/`Else`, using instead a conditional `Set`:

```bat
Rem ------------------------------------------------------
Rem -- Function Check In AD GROUP
Rem ------------------------------------------------------
:Check_ADGroup

Rem ======== Undefine Variable ========
Set "@InGroupYN="

Rem ======= Set to Yes if match =======
FindStr /IRC:"%~1" "%@ADGroups%" >Nul && Set "@InGroupYN=Y"

GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: can you add an explanation as to how this works or link to a source I can read up on as I'm not too familiar with the syntax - btw this works really well! Thanks

Comment: A variable is defined only if it has a value, `Set "@InGroupYN="` ensures that there is no `%@Ingroup%` variable by explicitly giving it no value. **`&&`** is a conditional executor, it sort of means 'if the last command was successful'. It has an opposite **`||`** which sort of means 'if the last command was unsuccessful'. _Every command does not report success or otherwise the same, `FindStr` is one which does._

Comment: Thanks Compo. Just one last question. Why does Findstr no need to for loop as I had before?

Comment: Because you're not saving its returned value, just its success or otherwise is needed.